# Does Ubuntu 20.04 nginx support range requests?

Tags: nginx

It implies in [https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/][1] that nginx supports range requests only if Cache Slicing is compiled into nginx.

Does Ubuntu 20.04 nginx support range requests?

Comment: "Range requests"? What do you mean by "Range requests"? What have you tried?

Comment: AFAIK range requests allow big files to be downloaded in parts so that the download can resume if there is a timeout or crash. I haven't tried anything yet but I've seen comments by people who've used a browser or an Android app to download a large file e.g. from Google of a SDK platform.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `nginx-extras` and `nginx-full` package should have it (at least has it in [debian](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nginx-extras)).

But you could find it out by yourself:

```
?sudo? nginx -V 2>&1 | tr " " "\n" | grep slice
```

BTW, cache slicing is only necessary if you want support range request in dynamic (e. g. proxying) content. Moreover it is used to split or else to implement effective cache of big response in chunks, which are under your control on proxying side.

For a simple range request to static resource (e. g. clients accessing PDF files or archives) it is not needed at all, nginx can serve `Range: bytes=n-m` request without any issue.

Just try this to test it:

```bsh
curl -v -r 0-1000 --HEAD 'http://example.com/download/some-file.pdf'
```

and see whether it'd answer with `206 Partial Content`.

In this way you can even do it for any dynamic content without slice module too, e. g. using HTTP redirect to previously stored file in some download location "caching" your documents internally in one piece.
And `ngx_http_slice_module` is something for partial caching e. g. for splitting a large response in few small responses behind backend upstream.